# How can I get the content of the div tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape information from the posts I review using `Beautifulsoup`.

But I'm having a hard time with I guess the basics:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

q_id = 27606129
res = requests.get(f"https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/{q_id}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
content = soup.select(".review-content")
print(content)
```

Output:

```
[<div class="review-content"></div>]
```

I want to get the things *inside* the `review-content` class, but this program just returns it empty.

More specifically, I want the data value inside the

```
<div class="js-vote-count grid--cell fc-black-500 fs-title grid fd-column ai-center c-pointer" itemprop="upvoteCount" data-value="0" role="button" tabindex="0" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" data-controller="null s-tooltip" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-7e7tvmxp">0</div>
```

tag, but it just returns nothing.

Comment: you've given two different html codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, so `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


q_id = 27606129
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/{}"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url.format(q_id))
# Wait for the page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
content = soup.select(".review-content")
print(content)

driver.quit()
```

**Edit:** to select the vote count:

```
vote_count = soup.select_one("div[itemprop='upvoteCount']").text
```